# Hibernate is unable to retrieve a value

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have following classes and need to execute a criteria on them, but hibernate does not find the property.

```
Class Car extends Vehicle
{
    String name;
    getter and setter of name;
}

Class Vehicle {
    Engine engine;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Engine getEngine() {
     return engine;
    }

    setter goes here 
}

Class Engine {
   String name;
   getter and setter of name;

}
```

My Code

```
    ....
    Criteria cre = session.createCriteria(Car.class,"car");
    cre.add(Restrictions.eq("engine.name", "314Full));
    return (Car) cre.list().get(0);
    ....
```

It runs into following error

**could not resolve property: engine.name of: com.myproject.car**

Comment: the engine property is set in the Vehicle and not Car class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
session.createCriteria(Car.class,"car").createAlias("engine","engine");
```